# Reactjs get SVG Polygon points loaded via image src and place the label text in center / optimal spot

Tags: javascript, svg, text, label, point-in-polygon

Input can be any SVG Polygon image of different irregular sizes as below

```
logo.svg
--------
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon points="100,100 150,25 150,75 200,0"
            fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Have to find a efficient way to read those polygon points loaded through image tag as mentioned below

```
import React from 'react';
{/*images*/}
import logo from './logo.svg'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={logo } alt="SVG Image" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

With polygon points, have to calculate the optimal spot within a SVG polygon to place the text label dynamically